# How to use pointer to acces a struct on C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to acces my struct with pointer but I can't, I think there is something wrong with my syntax. Here my syntax

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "str.h"
void main()
{
    typedef struct t_matakuliah t_mata_kuliah;
    t_mata_kuliah mk_mhs2;
    t_mata_kuliah *p_mk = mk_mhs2;
    p_mk->kode_mk;
    p_mk->nama_mk;
    p_mk->sks;
    printf("%s\n", p_mk->kode_mk);
    printf("%s\n", p_mk->nama_mk);
    printf("%d\n", p_mk->sks);
}
```

But if I use dot operator to acces it, it works.

this is my struct

```
struct t_matakuliah{
    char kode_mk[10], nama_mk[50];
    int sks;
};
```

Comment: `t_mata_kuliah *p_mk = &mk_mhs2;`

Comment: `structs` are nor `arrays`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that pointers point to the **address of** something.But here

```
t_mata_kuliah *p_mk = mk_mhs2;
```

you assign the pointer `p_mk` to  `mk_mhs2` instead of the address of it. To get the address of it,simply add an ampesand before `mk_mhs2` so that it looks like this:

```
t_mata_kuliah *p_mk = &mk_mhs2;
```

---

Arrays cannot be assigned,i.e, they are not assignable. As for `char` arrays,you can use [`strcpy`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm) to copy a string to the array. For example

```
strcpy(p_mk->kode_mk, "String");
strcpy(p_mk->nana_mk, "SecondString");
```

Answer (score 0):

t_mata_kuliah *p_mk = mk_mhs2;

In this line you have to assign the address to that pointer variable.  Give the code like this.

t_mata_kuliah *p_mk = &mk_mhs2;

It will work.

Comment: ok, thank you for your answers but how can I give a values for the field, I try to do it like this
typedef struct t_matakuliah t_mata_kuliah;
 t_mata_kuliah mk_mhs2;
 t_mata_kuliah *p_mk = &mk_mhs2;
 p_mk->kode_mk="Ab167";
 p_mk->nama_mk="Algoritma dan Pemrograman";
 p_mk->sks=3;
but it's not working

Comment: You can use the strcpy function for this. strcpy(p_mk->kode_mk,"Ab167");
strcpy(p_mk->nama_mk,"Algoritma dan Pemrograman"); Integer assignment will work correctly.